# How to prevent form remote submit in grails?

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, gsp

```
<g:formRemote name="form1" update="homeBody" 
              url="[controller: 'xxx', action:'aaa']">       
<Button type="submit">Save</Button>    
</g:formRemote>
```

I have situation to have one text field outside of the form. the value is set by javascript function.

If the text field has value, form will submit. If not, i have to prevent form submit. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The grails tag **g:remoteForm** can have a **before** attribute. The value of this attribute, according to Grails documentation is:

> The JavaScript function to call before the remote function call. A semi-colon is automatically added so you don't have to provide one yourself in this string.

So you can prevent form submission this way:

```
<g:formRemote name="form1" update="homeBody" 
              url="[controller: 'xxx', action:'aaa']"
              before="return checkTheField()">
    <Button type="submit">Save</Button>    
</g:formRemote>
```

Where checkTheField() is a javascript function, that returns **true** or **false** depending on the field checking result.

P.S. I suggest you to use grails **g:submitButton** tag instead of plain HTML **Button** tag for uniformity.

Comment: Thank you for reply Alex.i used this. i call js function from before. I got error like that function is not defined. But if i write the code in before, it work perfectly. what is the problem here.

Comment: You should define your function in external *.js file, for example, in application.js. And then you have to attach this file to your gsp template via <r:require modules="application" /> and <r:layoutResources /> in the head section. For more information about resources, check this out: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#resources